# Why use user@privatedomain@smtp.gmail.com in Mutt configuration file?

Tags: mutt, smtp

I cannot authenticate to my university smtps server with Mutt, with the same error message as [“SASL authentication failed” with mutt and Gmail, why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81924/sasl-authentication-failed-with-mutt-and-gmail-why)

```
L'authentification SASL a échoué
Impossible d'envoyer le message.
```

Or, in English:

```
SASL authentication failed
Impossible to send the message.
```

The thing is, the smtps server I use uses SSL/TLS authentication, not SASL (I do not know what this is).
Second, my .muttrc is configured with

```
set smtp_url = smtps://user@smtps.domain:465
```

With Thunderbird this configuration works fine, so I wonder why in the link above Rinzwind says to

```
set smtp_url = "smtps://username@domain.ex@smtp.gmail.​​​com:465/
```

Is this going to make my sent email pass through Google servers? Because I certainly don't want that!

Answer (score 2):

In the referenced link somebody is asking how to use `mutt` together with Gmail. The given answer is therefor pointing to the Gmail servers. If you want to setup mutt to use an external email server see http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Sendmail, especially the **How do I configure Mutt to use a remote SMTP server to send mail?** section which states:

```
set smtp_url="smtp://yourusername@smtp.example.com:587/"
set smtp_pass="Your1!Really2@AweSome3#Password"
```

To use TLS you should add also the following directives:

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes
```